# Selenium Webdriver using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium Webdriver :   In this code My Test case is passing for one Test Email Account but for the second test mail it is skipping the code , it does not pass the second test email

```
package Packet;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    // = new ChromeDriver();
    // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/rohit/Desktop/chromedriver");
    public String baseurl = "http://google.com";

    @BeforeTest
    public void launchbrowser()

    {
        System.out.println("LaunchBrowser called...");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/rohit/Desktop/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseurl);
    }
    // *[@id="gmail-sign-in"]//*[@id="gbw"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a

    @BeforeMethod
    public void Beforemethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello Before Method");
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void GmailTap() {
        System.out.println("Test priority 0 called...");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbw\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gmail-sign-in\"]")).click();

        System.out.println("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        // Thread.sleep(8000);
        // driver.close();
        // findElement(By.cssSelector(""))
        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
        // CharSequence charSequence = new
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
                System.out.println("Executed");
                flag = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_71\"]")).click();

    }
    // _____________

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void GmailTap2() {
        System.out.println("Test priority 1 called...");
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbw\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();

        System.out.println("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc1@gmail.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
                System.out.println("Executed");
                flag = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_71\"]")).click();

    }

    // ____________

    @AfterMethod
    public void aftersignout1() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account-chooser-link\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account-chooser-add-account\"]")).click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void aftersignout() {
        System.out.println("aftersignOut called...");
        // New Accnt
        driver.close();
    }
    // *[@id="account-chooser-add-account"]

}
```

Output is shown as :

```
LaunchBrowser called...
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 25912
Only local connections are allowed.
Hello Before Method
Test priority 0 called...
hello
Executed
Hello Before Method
Test priority 1 called...
[340.657][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

Comment: why u initiate and destroying ur webdriver instance for each test case again and again...try to initiate for one time in the @ BeforeTest annotation and destroy it at @ AfterTest annotation

Comment: @Noor , I updated my code through your explanation but it is giving me a error that Unable to receive message from renderer.Can u please have a look at my code

Answer (score 0):

hi in @AfterMethod instead of driver.close(); please use driver.quit();

Comment: This din't worked for me. However I updated my code but this din't worked.

Comment: getting same issue or sth else

Comment: Different issue as:LaunchBrowser called... Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 25912 Only local connections are allowed. Hello Before Method Test priority 0 called... hello Executed Hello Before Method Test priority 1 called... [340.657][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer

Comment: skipping the test case for 2nd test email

Answer (score 0):

the following code works like a charm for me

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseurl = "http://google.com";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchbrowser()

    {
        System.out.println("LaunchBrowser called...");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/your/path/to/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseurl);
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void GmailTap() {
        System.out.println("Test priority 0 called...");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();

        System.out.println("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc1@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

        boolean flag = true;

        while (flag) {

            try {
                driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
                System.out.println("Executed");
                flag = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_71\"]")).click();

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void GmailTap2() {
        System.out.println("Test priority 1 called...");
        System.out.println("Test priority 0 called...");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();

        System.out.println("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc1@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
                System.out.println("Executed");
                flag = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")));
        myDynamicElement.click(); // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
                                    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_71\"]")).click();

    }

    // ____________

    @AfterMethod
    public void aftersignout() {
        System.out.println("aftersignOut called..."); // New Accnt

        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account-chooser-link\"]")));
        myDynamicElement.click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account-chooser-add-account\"]")).click();
        driver.quit();
    } // *[@id="account-chooser-add-account"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my Output

```
package Packet;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {

     boolean flag = true;
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseurl = "http://google.com";



    @BeforeTest
     public void launchbrowser()

    {
        System.out.println("LaunchBrowser called...");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/rohit/Desktop/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseurl);
    }


    @BeforeMethod
    public void Beforemethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello Before Method");
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void GmailTap() {
        System.out.println("Test priority 0 called...");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbw\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
        System.out.println("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
                System.out.println("Executed");
                flag = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_71\"]")).click();

    }





    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void GmailTap2() {
        System.out.println("Test priority 1 called...");
        System.out.println("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("123456");
                System.out.println("Executed");
                flag = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_71\"]")).click();

    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void aftersignout1() {

        if (flag)
         {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account-chooser-link\"]")).click();
         flag = false;
         }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account-chooser-add-account\"]")).click();
    }
    //*[@id="account-chooser-add-account"]
    @AfterTest
    public void aftersignout() {
        System.out.println("aftersignOut called...");
        // New Accnt`enter code here`
        driver.close();
    }
    }
```